# Structure of the weight-module generated by a primitive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra with CSA $\mathfrak h$. Let $R \subset \mathfrak h^*$ be the set of roots. Let $\Pi \subset R$ be a base of $R$ and $R^+$ the set of positive roots w.r.t. that base. Let $V$ be a $\mathfrak g$-representation.
For $\alpha \in \mathfrak h^*$ denote by $\mathfrak g_\alpha \subset \mathfrak g$ the root space of $\alpha$ and by $V_\alpha \subset V$ the weight space of $\alpha$.
One shows the following *lemma*:

> For $\alpha, \lambda \in \mathfrak h^*$ the inclusion $\mathfrak g_\alpha V_\lambda \subset V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ holds.

Define $\mathfrak n^+:=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^+}\mathfrak g_\alpha$, $\mathfrak n^-:=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^+}\mathfrak g_{-\alpha}$. Let $v \in V_\lambda$, $v\neq 0$ be a primitive element (that is, $\mathfrak n^+ \cdot v=0$).
I am looking at a proof of the following fact:

> The $\mathfrak n^-$–subrepresentation $\tilde{V}$ of $V$ generated by the vector $v$ is a $\mathfrak g$–subrepresentation of $V$and has the form $\tilde{V}=\bigoplus_{\mu \leq \lambda}\tilde{V_\mu}$ with $\tilde{V_\lambda}=\mathbb C v$.

The proof begins as follows:

> By the above *lemma* we directly have $\tilde{V} \cap V_\lambda=\mathbb C v$ and $\tilde{V}=\bigoplus_{\mu \leq \lambda}\tilde{V_\mu}$.

Unfortunately, I don‘t see how this follows directly from the lemma. Any hints (or an explanation)?

**Added on 11th February:**
Since by the above lemma the linear subspace $W:=\mathbb C v \bigoplus_{\mu <\lambda} V_\mu$ defines a $\mathfrak n^-$–subrepresentation of $V$ and $v \in W$, the inclusion $\tilde{V} \subseteq W$ holds. Therefore, $V_\lambda \cap \tilde{V}=\tilde{V_\lambda}\subseteq W_\lambda=\mathbb Cv.$ The other inclusion $\mathbb Cv \subseteq V_\lambda \cap \tilde{V}$ holds trivially.

I think my question comes from the fact that I do not know how (given a $\mathfrak g$-representation $V$) the $\mathfrak g$–subrepresentation of $V$ generated by an element $v \in V, v \neq 0$ looks like. It is the intersection of all $\mathfrak g$-subrepresentations of $V$ containing $v$, right?
Is it equal to the following set union $\cup_{r \in \mathbb Z _{\geq 0}}V(r)$ where $V(r)=span\{Y_1\cdot...\cdot Y_i v|1 \leq i \leq r, Y_k \in \mathfrak g\}$? I am looking for a description that is equally nice as in group theory where the subgroup generated by an element $g$ is simply the set $\{g^i|i \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Well you know that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak n^+ \oplus \mathfrak n^- \oplus \mathfrak g_0$, and $\mathfrak g_0 = \mathfrak h$, right? So if you let all of $\mathfrak g$ act on $v$, basically only what part(s) of $\mathfrak g$ act on it? And those parts by the lemma can "move" the weight space only in what direction?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Only $\mathfrak n^- \bigoplus \mathfrak h$ acts non-trivially. It can only move the weight spaces down. Please see my addition to the question above.

Comment: Your addition looks correct to me and seems to solve your original question.